# Recommendation for javascript form validation library

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Any recommendations for a javascript form validation library. I could try and roll my own (but I'm not very good at javascript). Needs to support checking for required fields, and preferably regexp validation of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this library](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation) for a couple of personal projects. It's pretty good, though I have had to make my own modifications to it a couple of times - nothing major, though, and it's easy enough to do so.

I'm sure you already do this, but also validate all of your information on the server-side, as well. Client-side-only validation is rarely, if ever, a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

I am about to start implementing javascript validation in my forms using [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).
I think that StackOverflow users this jQuery plugin as well. It seems to be a very mature validation library, however it does build on top of jQuery, so it might not fit for you.

Like Tom said, don't forget that server side validation.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I just rolled my own because it was much simpler to integrate with my error handling system and how I wanted it displayed on the site.  99% of the time you only care about a couple of things, required fields and comparing fields.