# Validation library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any validation library in JavaScript? I'm looking for something small, simple and basic.

**Example 1**

```
var email = "steve@jobs.com";

if ( validate(email, "email") ) {

  // Success

}
```

**Example 2**

```
var email = "steve@jobs.com";

if ( validate(email, {
  "length": [0, 12],
  "characters": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ...],
}) ) {

  // Success

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What kinds of things do you want to validate?

Comment: Validating email addresses in particular is probably a pointless exercise, since even if you get the *form* of the address blessed personally by the Pope it may not actually work when you get around to sending it some email.

Comment: That said, basic structural validation is probably a helpful "typo-buster" for people filling in forms.

Comment: @Nick Email, phone, address, username, my custom field types, etc.

Comment: The real "holy grail" is to have this sort of superficial, "first order" data validation be driven by rules defined at the server and shared *to the greatest extent possible* by all appropriate levels of server code *and* the client code.

Comment: @Pointy - The pope validates email addresses? does he have an API?

Comment: It would be handy to have such a validation library that would enable us to validate everyday items such as email, date etc.

Comment: @Nick you have to trade in a Holy Grail for the service (except on 4 Oct when email addresses etc. count as "animals") *-- prepares to be struck by lightning --*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendation for javascript form validation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817/recommendation-for-javascript-form-validation-library)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to validate emails, check out this link:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/js-validation.php

And here's phone number validation:

http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/phone_no_validation.asp

(To answer your question directly, I don't know of any validation libraries :) )

Comment: Thanks for the link! I would like to validate not only email, but also  username, phone, my custom fields, etc.

Comment: How would you validate a username? Just prevent e.g. numbers from being in them?

Comment: Yes, I will just specify my own rules for username (length: 0 - 12, no numbers, no spaces, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at 
[jquery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)

Answer (score 0):

For form validation based on some common types, perhaps see my [Form AutoValidate](http://phrogz.net/JS/FormAutoValidate/formautovalidate_docs.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/search/javascript/form+validation), there, in hotscripts you have a couple of options.