# HTML5 form validation? Something more 'elegant' than an alert box?

Tags: javascript, validation, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendation for javascript form validation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817/recommendation-for-javascript-form-validation-library)

I've got a HTML5 login form. The user enters their Username and Password. Currently if the password is incorrect an alert box is thrown which informs them. However, alert boxes are ugly and make everything look horrible. I'm looking for alternatives, easy to implement ideas that others find much more elegant. Something you don't have to click to get rid of but make it very aparent to the user what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to check nice jQuery plugin for form validation:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a jQuery hide/show of an error message along side the offending text box is what you need.

Your question suggests that the validation is being done on the client side, not the server.  If that's not correct, you can make an Ajax call to the server with the credentials.  Your server can do the lookup in the directory or database, determine whether the person is a valid user, and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with duffymo.

If the password field is incorrect for instance, instead of an alert box you can probably try using a colored border to highlight the field(use filters and shadowbox for better effects) and make span element come along side the password field indicating that the user has entered the wrong data (You can use a text and image combo or just plain text, concise.) and fadeout the span element after sometime. I have used this concept extensively for some of the pages i have created in my company.