# Form shouldn't be submitted if Check box is not selected

Tags: javascript, html, validation, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendation for javascript form validation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817/recommendation-for-javascript-form-validation-library)

In my HTML page there is a `radio button`, if that radio button is selected it will enable a `div` containing a `textbox`.

I need some validation here. If the `checkbox` is selected and `textbox` is empty then the `submit button` should not work and it should remain on the same page.

How can i implement this?

> > > edited the code so that it will work now.

How can I implement this in Play! Framework?
This is a part of my code

```
<div id="ask-poll">
    <form name="myform" action="@{Application.askquestion()}" onsubmit="return validateThisForm();">
    <div class="wf-group">
      <p><label for="questionText"><h3>Who do you want to ask for their opinion?</h3></label></p>
```

Comment: Can You use jquery or clean javascript ?

Comment: See e.g. [Recommendation for javascript form validation library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817/recommendation-for-javascript-form-validation-library)

Comment: @Pekka: Might as well have just linked directly to the jquery validation plugin (even though this is not a jquery question). That's the only thing of value in the "duplicate". The only other offering there is some random code from 2007 that doesn't even work. Folks really need to check out these supposed duplicates before blindly throwing them at people, there are now two others who are copying the close vote.

Comment: @Wesley I *did* check out the dupe link; the jQuery validation plugin answer is the highest voted one there (although that admittedly may not be obvious for a newbie). If you have a better dupe suggestion, provide it and add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isnt a coded answer, there are a number of form validation javascript examples (hence Im not going to insult you by posting a bunch of links to them) where you can see how they use javascript to test if all the required elements are completed, eg, various "required" textboxes, a "have you read this" checkbox etc. You then implement this as part of the submit "onclick" and if its not valid you return "false" this prevents the form being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

This has been taken from @danyolgiax's link

```
function theChecker()
{ 
if(document.theForm.theCheck.checked==false)
{
document.theForm.theButton.disabled=true;
}
else
{
document.theForm.theButton.disabled=false;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case You want to use jquery here is a sample code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#somediv").hide(); //hide div
    $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled"); //disable submit button
    function checkAll()  //prepare function for disabling / enabling submit button
    {
        if($('input[type=text]').val() == '')
        {
            $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
    $('input[type=text]').bind('mouseenter mouseleave focus blur keypress', function() {
        checkAll();
    });  //bind function for text input, checking if its empty or not and calling checkAll() function

    $('input:radio')click(function() // bind function for radio that will show div after clicking
    {
        $("#somediv").show();
    });
}
```